# Passing objects subclass type

Tags: java, android, class, casting

I am working with a function that takes a class type as parameter:

I am trying to pass getSpans() the specific subclass of the Object "type."

```
Spannable ss;
Object type;
int start;
int end;

//Assume above variables properly initialized.
....

//getSpans(int start, int end, Class<T> type)
ss.getSpans(start, end, ???);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `type.class`. It will return the Class object of the type variable. Also try `type.getClass().class`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Better use the 2nd example.

Comment: `type` is an instance, so `type.class` is not valid. Also, `type.getClass()` returns a `Class` object. The `Class` type doesn't have a public member called `class`, so `type.getClass().class` is also not valid.

Comment: You were right chloe.  I edited my question so others don't get swept up in my confusion (since I was saying getClass didn't work).   I tried getClass, and it wasn't returning matches due to a coding error.   btw..u can't get object.class of an instance, you're only option is getClass() (that I'm aware of) which is the point I think mike is making.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality without resorting to a series of instanceof's by using the Strategy Pattern.  Here is an example implementation that calculates shipping costs using different providers without actually having to know what provider type is used.

```
public enum ShippingMethod {
    FIRST_CLASS {
        public double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles) {
            // Calculate the shipping cost based on USPS First class mail table
        }
    },
    FED_EX {
        public double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles) {
            // Calculate the shipping cost based on FedEx shipping
        }       
    },
    UPS {
        public double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles) {
            // Calculate the shipping cost based on UPS table
        }           
    };

    public abstract double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles);
};

public class ShippingInfo {

    private Address address;
    private ShippingMethod shippingMethod = ShippingMethod.FIRST_CLASS;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles) {
        return shippingMethod.getShippingCost(weightInPounds, distanceInMiles);
    }
}
```

More info on the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [full example](http://www.jroller.com/cardsharp/entry/strategy_pattern_using_java_5).